# How to rank by the specific field in the same score when using DisjunctionMaxQuery in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

I am searching an index with 3 it's fields ("name", "addr" and "fullname"), and using a `DisjunctionMaxQuery` to rank the results by the max score of 3 fields.  When the hits have same score, lucene ranks them by doc Id (low doc Id would be first).

But I don't want to rank by doc Id in that case.  I would like to rank by field. If the hits have the same score, I expect that the hit whose score (max score) is from the field "name" would be before the hit whose score is from another field.

I think the customer Collector & HitQueue is good idea and rewrite the method PriorityQueue.lessThan could change rank in priority queue. Unfortunately, the info in ScoreDoc is too little, and it's hard to get the source of max score for every hit.

Someone else know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach to this would be to simply boost the fields you want to come first in a tie slightly more than the other:

```java
Query query = new DisjunctionMaxQuery(0);

Query subQueryOne = new TermQuery(new Term("one", searchterm))
subQueryOne.setBoost(1.2);

Query subQueryTwo = new TermQuery(new Term("two", searchterm))
subQueryOne.setBoost(1.1);

Query subQueryThree = new TermQuery(new Term("three", searchterm))
subQueryOne.setBoost(1.0);

query.add(subQueryOne);
query.add(subQueryTwo);
query.add(SubQueryThree);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. setBoost usually is a good approach. It would solve the problem. But it also would bring in a new problem that will make a change to the score of these fields. I could not be sure wether it would influence our search experience.

Comment: Of course you could.  You simply make the boost difference adequately small.

Comment: I would like these fields have the same weights(boosts) when scoring. I think the only factor for scoring is the text relevance of query and documents.

Comment: I have been trying to rewrite DisjunctionMaxScorer , code custom Collector and overwrite HitQueue.lessThan. I want to attach ScoreDoc with some field information or tag. But I found this is difficult and can't get information of the fields from Scorer. Finally, if I can't slove it by my approach, I will adopt your idea setting boost to instead of mine. Thanks for your help. ;)